# Generic Inheritance changing super data field to const [from HW]

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have a class A and I want to write a class B that inherits from class A.

Code for class A:

```
template<class S, class T>
class A {
protected:
    S data1;
    T data2;
public:
    ...
};
```

Code for class B:

```
template<class S, class T>
class B: public A {
protected:
    B<S, T>* next;
public:
    ...
}
```

How can I inherit data1 field from A but make it const in B?

Comment: Make it private in class A and add a protected (or public) 'get' function for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't even compile as is (missing template arguments for `A`), and fixing it also offers a hint for solving your problem. This is one way of doing it (assuming I've understood your question correctly):

```
template<class S, class T>
class B: public A<const S, T> {
protected:
    B<S, T>* next;
public:
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `private` members:

```
template<class S, class T>
class A {
private:
    S data1;
protected: // Or private with accessor
    T data2; 
public:
    ...
};   


template<class S, class T>
class B: public A<S, T> { 
protected:
    B<S, T>* next;
public:
    ...
};
```

So you cannot modify `data1` in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and should not. It could cause major problems if a member had different cv-qualifiers in `B` as opposed to `A`.

For instance:

```
void A::foo()
{ 
  //do something to data1
}

void B::bar() 
{
  if (//data1 invariant)
    foo(); // invariant changed
  if (//data1 invariant)
    //due to const propagation we enter here, but the invariant isn't kept
}
```